# wp_enqueue_scripts hook is not being called

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, front-end

I added the following code to my `functions.php`:

```
if(!function_exists('bi_frontend_scripts')) {
    function bi_frontend_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        // I originally wanted to do:
        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery.bxSlider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/scripts/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bi_frontend_scripts');
```

But apparently neither of the scripts is being enqueued. I didn't get what my problem was, so I added this script to find out if the hook is called:

```
function aal_handler() {
    static $list = array();
    // exclude certain actions:
    $exclude = array('gettext', 'gettext_with_context');

    $action = current_filter();

    if(!in_array($action, $exclude)) {
        $list[] = $action;
    }
    // shutdown is the last action
    if ('shutdown' == $action) {
        print '<pre>' . implode( "\n", $list ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
add_action('all', 'aal_handler', 99999, 99);
```

And in the list `wp_enqueue_scripts` does not appear. So why the hook is not called?!

Comment: Maybe `bi_frontend_scripts()` was defined previously and therefore doesn't pass the check for its non-existence?

Comment: No, I already took this into account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, though I would not add the callback if the function name has already been used. If someone else has used the name you don't know what you might be adding.

```
if(!function_exists('bi_frontend_scripts')) {
    function bi_frontend_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        // I originally wanted to do:
        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery.bxSlider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/scripts/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bi_frontend_scripts');
}
```

I also tested your "hook dump" function-- `aal_handler()`-- and that works. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is part of the output.

I have to conclude that there is something wrong with the theme. [`wp_enqueue_scripts` is hooked to `wp_head`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L198), which fires in the [`wp_head()` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1633). The most obvious possibility is that your theme is not using `wp_head()` correctly, or at all. Another distant possibility is that something has removed your callback-- for example, with:

```
remove_all_filters('wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: Dump me… I was totally missing `wp_head()`! Thanks, I just didn't see the wood for the trees! :-)

Comment: wp_head() shoot me

Answer (score 4):

For anyone getting this problem in an **admin** page, use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

[Documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).

Answer (score -2):

I am here again with a lot of information for you so that you understand how things work with `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

You need to know the priority order for the `wp_enqueue_scripts`. See hook order below:

1. muplugins_loaded
2. registered_taxonomy
3. registered_post_type
4. plugins_loaded
5. sanitize_comment_cookies
6. setup_theme
7. load_textdomain
8. after_setup_theme
9. auth_cookie_malformed
10. auth_cookie_valid
11. set_current_user
12. **init**
13. widgets_init
14. register_sidebar
15. wp_register_sidebar_widget
16. wp_default_scripts
17. wp_default_stypes
18. admin_bar_init
19. add_admin_bar_menus
20. wp_loaded
21. parse_request
22. send_headers
23. parse_query
24. pre_get_posts
25. posts_selection
26. wp
27. template_redirect
28. get_header
29. wp_head
30. **wp_enqueue_scripts**
31. wp_print_styles
32. wp_print_scripts

...and so on.

So you see you can add it in the `init` hook and doing so it will be called as high priority than below the listing.

If your files are not loading you could use a higher priority hook.

If your `wp_enqueue_script` is not being called, you can use this simple trick to get it working for your theme or plugin.

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('bi_frontend_scripts')) {
    function bi_frontend_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        // I originally wanted to do:
        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery.bxSlider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/scripts/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'));
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'bi_frontend_scripts' );
}


?>
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script()` should never be called in the `init`, that is why the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action is there. This is just bad practice

Comment: surely you can call it when you need it. How will you call default wordpress js files? Please check this article for reference https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11526